# Import tuples from file

Tags: python

My .txt file:

```
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
(241, 151, 16)
```

how can I import these from a text file as tuples instead of strings

what I have currently:

```
save_file = open('save.txt', 'r');
if os.stat('save.txt').st_size != 0:
  for lines in save_file:
   _var = tuple(map(float, save_file.readline().split(',')))
```

(the last line of code was taken from a different post, but doesnt work)

Comment: What have you done until now?

Answer (score 1):

A safe way to convert this data to a list of tuples is to use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

with open('save.txt') as f:    
    result = list(map(ast.literal_eval, f))
```

Comment: Short and sweet :)

Answer (score 1):

A few mistakes:

```
for lines in save_file:
```

it's not "lines" it's one line, you're iterating one line at a time.

Second, you're using `save_file.readline()` instead of using the line that you're iterating on.

Third, when you parse a string that looks like: `line = '(241, 151, 16)'` you should remove the parenthesis from the start and end of the string:

```
line = line[1:-1]
```

and you should split not only by comma, but by comma and the space that follows it:

```
line.split(', ')
```

Let's put it together:

```
for line in save_file:
   line = line[1:-1]
   _var = tuple(map(float, line.split(', ')))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in much cooler way, see answer from @Raymond, but I have followed what you have done until now.

You should read the file and use [literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method from [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module.

```
import os
import ast

save_file = open('save.txt', 'r');
if os.stat('save.txt').st_size != 0:
    for line in save_file.readlines():
        a_tuple = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())
        print a_tuple, type(a_tuple)
```

Each line has `\n`, so I have used [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code has error because `"(241, 151, 16)".split(",")` is `["(241", " 151", " 16)"]`

You can use `re` library:

```
import re

# with `content` is list of row
list_of_tuple = [tuple(map(int, re.findall("\d+", text))) for text in content]
```

Comment: this made all the numbers in the tuple strings.

Comment: @DarkMonolith: if you need `int`, let's convert them